# Apart from SQL injection what other security vulnerabilities should I be aware of in a website?

Tags: php, html, css, security, codeigniter

I generally work using the codeigniter framework, which provides some help with preventing sql injection, e.g. xss clean of form input data.

I have a basic idea of what sql injection is and how to stop it happening, but a friend of mine has a very basic site in which the only user input was a cgi form to email script - parts of the site were replaced with some adult content.

So I am curious how someone could have gained control of such a basic site and also, what kind of vulnerabilities I should be aware of when building my own sites?

Comment: see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good place to start is [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/).

In particular the [OWASP Top 10 details the most common security issues](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project).

In principle you should...

- **Never** trust user input (including form input, URL input, cookies - anything the user could change including using inspection tools like Firebug or middle-man tools like Fiddler). There are loads of categories of this, but OWASP does cover them individually.
- **Never** trust scripts for other people (i.e. you include their JavaScript file in your website, or their PHP file in your website)
- **Never** perform a log-in or other sensitive data-exchange over plain HTTP

Answer (score 1):

you could check out www.enigmagroup.org/ very useful for learning about different attacks and vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the link - looks like the place to learn how its done from the other side... I will definitely check it out when I have time

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is read up on the OWASP top 10. If you aren't familiar with it, it's the Open Web Application Security Project and it is a community committed to web app security.

The top things that are easiest to exploit by a malicious user are SQL Injection and XSS. XSS Can be bad for your users but a single SQL Injection vulnerability can compromise your entire server. SQLI can be prevented by simply using parametrized queries and preventing XSS can be done by having good input validation and output encoding.

From a software engineering perspective, input supplied by the user (this includes hidden fields) should never drive core functionality. For example, if you are selling a product on your site and have a hidden field with the price, this is very bad because someone could modify that value very easily.

If you are collecting usernames and passwords, make sure they are hashed and salted and make sure that all login screens and pages that show or collect user information have SSL (https).

The OWASP top 10 documentation can be found at: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010

If you need help doing input validation and encoding, look at the OWASP ESAPI - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API and click on the PHP tab.

For SQL Injection, frameworks like codeigniter should protect you as long as you use the framework correctly. SQLI is becoming less and less of an issue due to the increased use of frameworks, thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

There are as many security issues as there are lines of code. Some examples:

- SQL injection
- XSS on the backend side (including remote code `require_once($_GET['x']`)
- XSS on the frontend side (including JAVASCRIPT into page to hijack a session)
- Running unwanted actions on users behalf - every action like "change
  password", "change profile", "logout", "add content" should require a
  unique token otherwise somebody can redirect a user into those
  actions
- if you release from `svn checkout` protect the .svn folder in every
  public directory

You can always use some scanners like http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/ to help you find security issues in your application.